# Generating a matrix so that correlations amongst columns are close to pre-defined values

Tags: correlation, graphical-model, synthetic-data

I want to generate a matrix of values such that the correlations (e.g., Pearsons correlations) are close to a pre-defined set of values (e.g., `corrs = [0.5, 0.7, -0.3, 0.9, 0.2]`). For simplicity, we can assume we're only concerned with the correlation of pairs of columns.

For example, I may want a matrix with 4 columns and 100 rows, and the correlations between columns should be close to the following:

```
CORR(c1, c2) = corrs[0]
CORR(c1, c3) = corrs[1]
CORR(c1, c4) = corrs[2]
CORR(c2, c3) = corrs[3]
CORR(c2, c4) = corrs[4]
CORR(c3, c4) = corrs[5]
```

Depending on the parameters specified (matrix size, correlations), a solution may not exist, but for reasonable parameters, it seems like some algorithm should be able to come up with a solution.

Is there any areas of research that can help me accomplish this?  It seems like something related to graphs and/or some iterative algorithm might be what I need, but I'm struggling with how to represent the problem mathematically or in a graph, and my knowledge of these areas is pretty limited.

Comment: It seems like a multivariate normal distribution (or multivariate Student's $t$ distribution, if you like) checks these boxes. Are there any additional requirements?

Comment: Thanks @Sycorax, that makes sense. I just adjust my covariance matrix accordingly.  I'll try playing with this

Comment: This might be what you're looking for http://www.econometricsbysimulation.com/2014/02/easily-generate-correlated-variables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Sycorax's recommendation, I used a multivariate normal distribution to generate my desired dataset.

I set the means and variances for my columns to 0 and 1 respectively, thus the covariance matrix is populated with just the desired Pearson correlations (since `cov(X,Y) = corr(X, Y) * std_dev_X * std_dev_Y`).

*Caveat to myself and others:* Apparently the covariance matrix should be positive-semidefinite for proper sampling to occur, so the input set of correlations will need to be arranged or modified to create a positive-semidefinite covariance matrix.